# Error JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_INVALID_CONTROLLER from CLI on Joomla 3.7

Tags: articles, custom-field, controller, cli

I have an issue with a **cli php script** that I'm trying to execute.
I want to add an article with *custom fields*.

The part where I add articles is working well, but when I add the code to load the article I just stored and set its custom fields values, there is the following error:

> Call to undefined method AddArticle::getTemplate(): **JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_INVALID_CONTROLLER**

The error seems to be related to the following line:

```
$article_joom = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Content')->getModel('Article')->getItem($article['id']);
```

I've tried to load the *ContentLoader* class because someone said it would help, but it didn't really change anything.

From what I've seen, I may not be able to use the JController on a cli script, but I haven't found another way to load articles.

Comment: What was the line # and file that called AddArtcile::getTemplate() ?

Comment: @Irata In my  script I created a class AddArticle extended to JApplicationCli. But never did I use any getTemplate method and the error doesn't give the name of a file or a line # . But I also get the following warning : Use of undefined constant JPATH_COMPONENT - assumed 'JPATH_COMPONENT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\V2\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php on line 232

Answer (score 2):

Start by updating to the latest version of Joomla - 3.9.20 - if you're able to first.

A number of changes regarding JControllerLegacy were made in Joomla 3.8 (see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/13683) and so that is certainly worth investigating first.

Next take a look at this post which relates to calling JController from CLI
[Call Controller's Publish-Method from CLI or Helper](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/call-controllers-publish-method-from-cli-or-helper)